# eclipse window builder work abnormaly in zorin os

Tags: java, eclipse, zorin

I am using zorin os 16 pro. I am using eclipse in windows machine for few months. It works fine in windows. But problem in zorin os. I download eclipse from [this](https://flathub.org/apps/details/org.eclipse.Java) site. All things are fine except window builder. The drag & drop, border is not correct. Like this image
[image]

I have installed WindowBuilder 1.9.8 and WindowBuilder Nightly Build 1.9.9. Is there any solution out there? Need help. I have googled but not find the solution yet.

Anyways, I love eclipse because I can customize all the code generated. Is there any alternative like eclipse? So that I can customize all codes include auto generated code? I have tried netbeans and intellij but I can not customize generated code.

Sorry for my bad english. Thanks to all.

I have tried saveral ways like change layout, drag and drop etc.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing is wrong here. The window decoration (the "border") is up to the window manager, it's not standardized; it will look different for different people, so to match how the rest of their system looks. So, eclipse shows you an "example", nothing more, of how the border *might* look like.

Comment: I have updated the image. please look at this. thanks for your response.